# How to draw border for group and child items?

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, baseadapter

Am using one expandable list view in my application. I didnt use any borders or backgrounds for group and child items.But I have to draw the border for group and child items WHEN THE GROUP IS EXPANDED with no dividers and lines i.e.Showing the group and child items in single box. I have tried many thing but only I got to draw for group or each child items.Please hepl me to resolve this.Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: Drawable is applied only to group headers not to child items.I need to draw box for group and correspondent child items WHEN A GROUP IS EXPANDED